# Can you check if there are any errors in the collada (.dae) models that I extracted?

Tags: game-engine, game-development, directx-11, collada, assimp

I used the Assimp loader in my DirectX 11 engine to open my .dae model files, but it's not functioning correctly.

My team and I don't believe there are any errors in my code, so I asked others for help. They suggested that there might be an issue with the model itself. I will upload the model files, and I would appreciate it if you could let me know if there are any problems with them.

The issues I anticipate are as follows:

Debugging results show that the values of the base vectors are incorrect.
The bone information I was manipulating is in local space, so the expected world position, rotation, and base are not being applied correctly.

[Model - Google drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gl6LV-4rlHUwJoTULTZQrLF5_KjkdYVp?usp=drive_link)

[image: my engine moddel]
[image: tool model]

**This is the code I used to load the model.**

```
void Model::recursiveProcessBoneMatrix(aiMatrix4x4 matrix, const std::wstring& nodeName)
{
    const ModelNode* modelNode = FindNode(nodeName);
    aiMatrix4x4 transform = modelNode->mTransformation;

    if (mParentModel)
    {
        // Code written to search for nodes with the same name in the model.
        ModelNode* parentModelNode = mParentModel->FindNode(nodeName);
        if (parentModelNode)
        {
            /*
            Set my hierarchy information based on the parent's corresponding node hierarchy.
            Although the model is forced to move to the position of that node, 
            it causes rotation issues.
            */
            Bone* bone = mParentModel->FindBone(nodeName);

            if (bone != nullptr)
            {
                bone = mParentModel->GetBone(bone->mIndex);

                matrix = bone->mLocalMatrix;
            }
        }
    }

    matrix = matrix * transform;


    if (mBoneMap.find(nodeName) != mBoneMap.end())
    {
        Bone* bone = &mBoneMap.find(nodeName)->second;
        aiMatrix4x4 glovalInvers = FindNode(L"Scene")->GetTransformation();

        // bone->mOffsetMatrix - vectex to bonespace (like world, view, projection transform)
        //matrix - transformed martrix from root
        bone->mFinalMatrix = glovalInvers.Inverse() * matrix * bone->mOffsetMatrix;
        bone->mLocalMatrix = matrix;

        mBones[bone->mIndex].mFinalMatrix = bone->mFinalMatrix;
        mBones[bone->mIndex].mLocalMatrix = matrix;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < modelNode->mChilds.size(); ++i)
    {
        recursiveProcessBoneMatrix(matrix, modelNode->mChilds[i]->mName);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is quite normal. All parts of the mesh will be centred at the model origin, and will only be translated to their proper relative positions in the scene after you apply the bone palette transforms. If your recursive bone matrix processing function isn't working, try investigating the order in which matrices are multiplied together, and also that you're passing in column-major matrices, which I think is what Assimp requires.